How use Cayley-Bacharach-Chasles Theorem (CBC)) for proof Pappus's theorem?
I have read the proof of the following theorem and I understand it,
I'm reading the book Perspectives on Projective Geometry - Jürgen Richter-Gebert
Theorem 1.5 (Cayley-Bacharach-Chasles Theorem (CBC)). Let $A$ and $B$ be two curves of degree three intersecting in nine proper points. If six of these points are on a conic, the remaining three points are colinear.
But also it says that considering respectively 3 lines and three other lines in the Pappus theorem we will have a two cubic to which we apply the theorem and what we wanted to show results, exactly it says the following

The rest is a literal application of the above theorem. One can
even go one step further and consider Pappos’s original theorem as a direct
consequence of Theorem 1.5. For this one simply has to consider three of the
lines as one cubic and another three as the other cubic

my question is why these three lines taken would they be a cubic?

What degree is $(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z)(a_2x+b_2y+c_2z)(a_3x+b_3y+c_3z)$?
